# having problems to create a vaadin 7 project while disconnected from internet

Tags: vaadin, web.xml, ivy, ubuntu-12.10

struggling to create a project using the vaadin eclipse plugin, eclipse doesn't find the version of vaadin, can't create the pre-configurations in the web.xml file automaticallyhave have to do it manually  and does not create the ivy.xml
I have attached some pictures ....

IT FAILS TO SHOW THE VAADIN VERSION
[image: eclipse]

IMPOSSIBLE TO SET VAADIN VERSION
[image: eclipse2]

I DON'T KNOW WHY THIS APPEARS BECAUSE I HAVE PROJECTS CREATED ALREADY BUT ONLY WHEN IM CONNECTED 
[image: eclipse3]

AND FINALLY THE WEB.XML
[image: web.xml]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having looked at the source of the Vaadin Eclipse plugin, it always checks online to see if there are to get the downloadable list of Vaadin Versions.

(See [VaadinProjectFirstPage](http://dev.vaadin.com/browser/svn/integration/eclipse/plugins/com.vaadin.integration.eclipse/src/com/vaadin/integration/eclipse/wizards/VaadinProjectFirstPage.java?rev=25858#L119), [VaadinVersionComposite](http://dev.vaadin.com/browser/svn/integration/eclipse/plugins/com.vaadin.integration.eclipse/src/com/vaadin/integration/eclipse/properties/VaadinVersionComposite.java?rev=25858#L145) and [DownloadManager](http://dev.vaadin.com/browser/svn/integration/eclipse/plugins/com.vaadin.integration.eclipse/src/com/vaadin/integration/eclipse/util/network/DownloadManager.java?rev=25858#L104) )

It appears that it's not currently possible to create a new Vaadin project using the Wizard within Eclipse Plugin without access to the internet - even if you've already downloaded the appropriate jars using Ivy.

I can see that this could be problematic - and I would suggest that you report this on the Vaadin Forum, where the plugin  developers may consider fixing this as a bug.

Comment: Thank you i will follow your advice